# Win + Left Batch script?

Tags: batch-file, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to maximize a window to the left side of the screen (Win + Left Arrow) using a batch script?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: To rephrase: within a .bat file, can you reproduce the same functionality as a Win-Left Arrow (Full height and dock to the left side). I know the whole workspace concept only came in with Windows 7/2008 R2 so that may limit the availability of your intent

Comment: Similar findings to @bali c Nothing out of the box with batch script but trivial with vbs  http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/58977-45-sending-right-shift-batch-file

Comment: Haha, thanks for the rephrasing.  I was a bit rushed when I typed that.  And yes, either that, or to resize the window to the height of the screen, and the width / 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with batch alone, but you might be able to use a vbscript with [SendKeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html). Then you can run the vb in batch with cscript.exe.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
```

[List of key strokes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

I'm not sure how you can do the Windows key, or if its possible with the codes in the link above. For that you may need something more powerful, like C#.

Comment: Could you give an example of the SendKey function I'd use to send Win + Left?  I can't seem to find one..

Comment: @mazzzzz Edited my answer with more details

Comment: Sadly it isn't possible with vb script either. I just sucked it up and used C#, though it's a bit bloated for my needs, hopefully I can use it in the future.  Thanks though